# React-Native : Space between underline text

Tags: react-native, react-native-text

I am using `style={{textDecorationLine: 'underline'}}`, but app currently shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCLtr.png).
But I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoeY0.png)

Comment: You can split the words into each word and wrap each word by a `<Text>`tag and apply the styles to each one. Obviously, this is not ideal, but you can do it easily via JS functions like `split()` and `join()`.
I don't know any other better way, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
renderTexts() {
    return textArray.map((item) => {
        return (
            <Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'underline'}}>{item.text}</Text>
        );
    });
}
...

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            { this.renderTexts() }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tested [example](https://snack.expo.io/@keyserve/37d9c1) on snack based on @Nooruddin Lakhani with some modifications.

the result:

[image]

the code:

```js
export default function App() {
  const textArray = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'];
  const renderTexts = () => {
    return textArray.map((item) => {
      return (
        <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline', marginLeft:2 }}>{item}</Text>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{renderTexts()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```